# node.js web crawler images/video

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, web-crawler

Recently I have been getting into web crawlers and I have figured out ow to search for text but is there any way that I can have my web crawler search for something else such as videos and images and then download them and organize them.

here is my web-crawler so far:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var fs = require('fs');

var START_URL = "https://www.google.com";
var SEARCH_WORD = "apples";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 200;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var url = new URL(START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
 crawl();

 function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
     return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
 numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request
 console.log("Visiting page " + url);
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
     // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
    }
    // Parse the document body
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var isWordFound = searchForWord($, SEARCH_WORD);
     if(isWordFound) {
      console.log('Word ' + SEARCH_WORD + ' found at page ' + url);
     } else {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       callback();
     }
  });
 }

function searchForWord($, word) {
  var bodyText = $('html > body').text().toLowerCase();
  return(bodyText.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}

 function collectInternalLinks($) {
     var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
relativeLinks.each(function() {
    pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
});
}
```

I have gotten most of this code from an online tutorial to help me get started but I need more help the code works I just wanted to know if and how would it be possible to web crawl images and video.

Newer Code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var fs = require('fs');

var START_URL = "http://moetube.net";
//var SEARCH_WORD = "anime";
 var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 200;

 var pagesVisited = {};
 var numPagesVisited = 0;
 var pagesToVisit = [];
  var url = new URL(START_URL);
 var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

 pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
 crawl();

 function crawl() {
   if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
     console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
     return;
   }
   var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
   if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
     // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
     crawl();
    } else {
       // New page we haven't visited
       visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
     }
   }

   function visitPage(url, callback) {
    // Add page to our set
    pagesVisited[url] = true;
    numPagesVisited++;

     // Make the request
     console.log("Visiting page " + url);
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
      console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
      collectImages($);
      if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
        callback();

          return;
       }
      // Parse the document body

     // var isWordFound = searchForWord($, SEARCH_WORD);

    // if(isWordFound) {
     //   console.log('Word ' + SEARCH_WORD + ' found at page ' + url);
    // } else {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       callback();
   //  }
   });
}

   function searchForWord($, word) {
   var bodyText = $('html > body').text().toLowerCase();
  return(bodyText.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }

function collectImages($) {

   return $("img").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
         console.log((this).text() + "JHJHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
     }).get();
      }

 function collectInternalLinks($) {

     var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
     console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
     relativeLinks.each(function() {
         pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
     });
 }
```

Comment: What does "web crawl images and video" mean?  You have the content of a web page in your crawler already parsed with cheerio.  You can use that find any images or video references in the page DOM.  What else are you asking?

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you i wasn't aware that that was possible thats why I'm asking

Comment: Well, you already have code that finds all the links in the page.   You can use similar code to find all the `<img>` tags or `<video>` tags.  If that's all you're trying to do, I can write an answer that shows that.  But, frankly I didn't understand what you means by crawl images and video because there's nothing to crawl.  With a link to another HTML page, you can load that page and then parse it.  With images or videos, there is no other crawling to do after you have the link because they don't have links embedded in them.  They are just endpoint media.

Comment: @jfriend00 that would be very nice if you could write an answer please. because right now i just want to figure out how they work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like you use cheerio to search the body for links, you can also search the body for either `<img>` or `<video>` tags.  You don't say exactly what you want to do when you find those tags, but you could create a function similar to your `collectInternalLinks()` that would collect media objects for further processing:

```
// return array of image URLs (these may be page-relative URLS)
function collectImages($) {
    return $("img").map(function() {
        return $(this).prop("src");
    }).get();
}

// return collection of video elements
function collectVideos($) {
    let videoUrls = [];
    $("video").each(function() {
        let src = $(this).prop("src");
        if (src) {
            videoUrls.push(src);
        } else {
            let subElements = $(this).find("track, source");
            subElements.each(function() {
                let src = $(this).prop("src");
                if (src) {
                    videoUrls.push(src);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return videoUrls;
}
```

Collecting video URLs is a bit more involved because those URLs can be specified a number of different ways (`.src` property, embedded `<track>` tags, embedded `<source>` tags, etc...) so you'd have to parse out each possible way for each `<video>` tag.

Comment: Ok thank you for the code, its just when ever i try to implement it, it always gives me a typeError: $ is not a function. any help?

Comment: or any way to implement it would help a lot.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - Just like in your other functions `collectInternalLinks()` and `searchForWord()`, you have to pass the cheerio instance to the functions as an argument.  That becomes the `$` argument.  Look at how your other functions work in this regard.

Comment: ok so the code is now from what i can tell working but it will not output the image links, what is the proper way to do this? thanks for all the help so far, I hope your not mad at me for asking so many questions.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - I can't comment on code I can't see.

Comment: ok i just updated the code into a new section called newer code

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - Why are you using `$(this).text()` on images?  As my answer clearly shows, the URL from an image is `this.src`.

Comment: im doing this because it gives me the same data which is nothing, ill change it back and see if it works. and i just changed it it still does not out to the console

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - What data are you trying to get from the image?

Comment: I'm tying to grab the images/video source so that i can download it.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - This is real frustrating for me because my answer already shows you how to get the img source.  I'm not sure why you tried something different.  Video source is more complicated because there are lots of ways that can be specified.

Comment: and what im saying is that the way you sent me does not return anything, it does not return the link for me.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - Did you debug it?  What does `this` point to?   What does `this.src` contain?  Does `this` have any useful properties?   What does the `.map()` argument named `item` point to.Y ou need to do some of your own debugging to solve these kinds of problems for yourself.  I don't have your code and HTML in front of me so I can't directly debug it.  You have to do that yourself.  Ideally you would use the debugger to set a breakpoint in the `.map()` loop and just look at what you have available there, but you can also just use lots of `console.log()` statements to investigate too.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - This is basic debugging/problem solving.  You need to learn how to do this yourself in order to be able to figure out things like this.  cheerio tries to present a jQuery-like interface, but I don't really know where it's different than jQuery to know exactly what will or will not work in cheerio.  That's where debugging would be extremely useful to see what properties cheerio is making available.

Comment: its returning but it only returns undefined it does not find the images on the page i think the code is broken. plus i cant always debug linke now where im running from a command prompt.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - I set up my own cheerio test environment and sample HTML file (I've never used cheerio before in my life) and looked at `this` in the debugger and then consulted the cheerio documentation and it works with `return $(this).prop("src");`. This took my about 15 minutes (only because I've never used it before). I've updated my answer to show that.  That code works.  You should be able to debug like this too.  If you don't know how, you must learn in order to be productive.

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 - I also added a `collectVideos()` function to my answer that works with some of the `<video>` formats (I don't know what format your HTML is using).